# Duplicate events in GA4 but not in GTM or Debuggers

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

For some time now, I am seeing duplicate events in a few of my GA4 properties. Many of them show multiple events done by one user. Meaning, I can see 6 submitted forms by 3 people. Due to the nature of the forms, I can say confidently that they would not submit twice. Moreover, I know from the actual submissions in GF that there were 3 forms sent in.

I am noticing this issue on multiple containers, with multiple events. All my events are send through GTM. The GTM preview mode however does not show multiple events firing. Neither does GA4 Debugger or Network Console.

I have fixed the issue in one container by adding a submission ID / Event ID parameter. I got this tip here https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-fix-duplicate-events-in-ga4/ . By doing so, GA4 registers that the events are the same (for they have the same event ID) and 'automatically' de-duplicates them. This is however not really targeting the root of the problem. But the fact that this solution works, tells me the issue must be in GA4.

Like I said, I send all events through GTM. I am pretty confident with the way the tracking is set-up. I have de-connected (and sometimes even deleted) my UA tracking. I know there is no double installation of GTM or GA4 code. The issue appears on sites with GTM hardcoded or through a WP plug-in.
I have tried to fix the issue by using different measurements of form submission in GTM (page_view of thank you page vs form submission) and both show this issue.

Comment: Ensure that your website does not load the GTM tag twice. Check the collect requests(you can find them by searching "v2") in the network tab to identify situations where events are sent twice.

Comment: Yeah, checked the network tab, but on the tag side everything is all good!